# Exchanging an image with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, image, src, attr

Can anybody tell me why the following code (also see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39s7S/)) does not replace *1tw.gif* with *2tw.gif*? It should show "2" instead of "1"...

```
<img id="pic" src="http://www.drewgreenwell.com/images/sample/1tw.gif" alt="" width="90%"/>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#pic').attr('scr', 'http://www.drewgreenwell.com/images/sample/2tw.gif');
});
</script>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have typo. `scr` should be `src`:

```
$('#pic').attr('src', 'http://www.drewgreenwell.com/images/sample/2tw.gif');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sUb4A/14/)**